# Is it true that $C_1\|\Delta u \|_{0,\Omega} \leq |u|_{2,\Omega} \leq C_2\|\Delta u \|_{0,\Omega}$ for a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let's say $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it true that

$C_1\|\Delta u \|_{0,\Omega} \leq |u|_{2,\Omega} \leq C_2\|\Delta u \|_{0,\Omega}$?

The left inclusion is obvious by definition. But I have no idea about the right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think the answer is no. For example, let $u=xy$ then $|u|_{2,\Omega} = \sqrt{|\Omega|}$, while $\| \Delta u\|_{0,\Omega}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes if $u$ has zero-boundary values and $\Omega$ is sufficiently regular. This follows from $H^2$-regularity of
\begin{align}-\Delta u &= f \text{ in } \Omega \\ u &= 0 \text{ on }\partial\Omega\end{align}
with $f = -\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$. Otherwise it may not hold.

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea. Function $u$ in the question only belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$, so it's not true in general.